# How to define multi-line @description metadata?

Tags: metadata, multiline, tampermonkey, userscripts, greasemonkey-4

None of the following works:

```js
// @description  ...text1...
// @description  ...text2...
```

Only `text2` is displayed.

```js
// @description  ...text1...
                 ...text2...
```

Only `text1` is displayed.

```js
// @description  ...text1...
//               ...text2...
```

Only `text1` is displayed.

```js
// @description  ...text1...<br />...text2...
```

Literal <br /> is displayed.

```js
// @description  ...text1...\n...text2...
```

Literal \n is displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.  The general idea was that the description was supposed to be concise ["Microcontent"](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/microcontent-how-to-write-headlines-page-titles-and-subject-lines/) and the size can't be too large without making the extension UI much more cumbersome.

The [Greasemonkey doc says](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40description):

> Just a **brief summary** of what the script does, presented to the user as the script is installed, and in the manage dialog.

The [Tampermonkey doc says](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_description):

> A **short** significant description.

The [Violentmonkey doc says](https://violentmonkey.github.io/api/metadata-block/#description):

> A **brief** summary to describe the script.

Now, you could submit feature requests or pull requests to try to get that changed but I think going for the [usability](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/microcontent-how-to-write-headlines-page-titles-and-subject-lines/)/TLDR/"Executive Summary" approach is better.

So:

1. Use an SEO-like ***useful***, **descriptive title**.
2. If the description seems to need **more than about 128 characters** (A) you're doing it wrong and/or (B) Link to a proper wiki/FAQ/homepage.
3. Make use of [the `@homepage`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_homepage) and [the `@supportURL`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_supportURL) keys.  Both **Tampermonkey and Violentmonkey will also use these to place link icons** in various places.  (You shouldn't be using Greasemonkey 4+, anyway, as discussed elsewhere.)

So here are some examples:

1. No description needed:

   ```
   // @name     YouTube, hide all comments.
   ```
2. Short description helps:

   ```
   // @name        YouTube, redirect to show only Yanni videos.
   // @description Chooses the best Yanni-related replacement for any YouTube video.
   ```
3. Really want lots of description:

   ```
   // @name        Stack Overflow, Insta-answer with guaranteed vote magnets.
   // @description See the terms, conditions and FAQS at stackingtheodds.mil.
   ```
4. Semi-useless description but full leverage of support URL's and icons:

   ```
   // @name        Stack Exchange, replace badge icons with duckies
   // @description Does what it says on the tin.
   // @homepage    https://stackapps.com/q/8116/7653
   // @supportURL  https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/blob/master/Stack%20Exchange,%20replace%20badge%20icons%20with%20duckies.user.js
   ```